# How to make a score function / equation

Tags: functions

There is given a **set** of **items** where some of them are **unimportant** and some of them have value on the scale 0.0 - 1.0.

So for example 10 items, 8 unimportant without score, and then 2 with score 0.3, and 0.8 respectively.

Now, what's the mathematic approach to compute the "score" of the set.

**Method 1:**

I can simply sum the values (pros: it reflects the existence of multiple important values, cons: larger sets have distorted score above the smaller sets)

**Method 2:**

Sum the values and do the average. (pros: none, cons: doesn't reflect the existence of multiple important values)

*I simply lack the idea how could I do it, please advice some methods.*

**Subquestion 1:**

How to give more importance to higher values (eg 0.9 over 0.2) I know there is a special approach for this called weighting, but first thing that came into my mind was to do the square. However in case of number smaller than 1 it won't work as expected. (0.9 x 0.9 = 0.81). So i was thinking multiply the value by 10 and do the square. However then i am out of initial 0 - 1 domain :).

So maybe the Weight function but have no idea about that.

**Subquestion 2:**

Same as above but do the weighting non linear / exponential, eg 0.9 more weighted than 0.8, 0.8 more then 0.7 etc. First idea that came to my mind was to use eg power of 3 instead of 2.

**Subquestion 3:**

How to make the score "index" so the score value will be on some scale eg 0-100 or 0-255. I was thinking to compute the score using the final method you will advice, and then compute the ratio of that score to score when all items or the items that had value are maxed to 1.0. (So ratio of current score to max score possible).

Thanks for the advices.

Comment: There are infinite many ways to define a function from a set into the real numbers. You should specify some properties to shrink that choice or go through the usual suspects (statistics, data science, machine learning) and try them out and see if those fit your needs.

Comment: if you could provide some examples then, i have no idea except the primitive methods i mentioned.

Comment: @luky, `@mvw` has given examples of fields that explore questions related to yours. But without specific knowledge of how the "score" is supposed to be used, there's no easy answer.